# Do any European politicians advocate for creating an European Army and leaving NATO?

Tags: european-union, military, nato

The United Kingdom with figures such as Thatcher being against a European army ([ref here](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/uk_news/politics/1034811.stm)) and Tony Blair ([ref here](https://www.rt.com/uk/329086-tony-blair-eu-army/)) who was for it, have been the most sceptical country towards the creation of a European Army. The British vision has been most of the time more for NATO and less for a European Army.

Now that the UK is meant to leave the European Union. Are there any remarkable politicians in favour of creating an European Army and perhaps eventually leaving NATO?

Comment: Have you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Security_and_Defence_Policy and it's closely associated articles? There _is_ already a EU military force distinct from NATO.

Comment: @PbxMan there is a bit of difference between the title and the body of your question - the body just asks about creating a European Army (which, as was mentioned, already exists since Maastricht Treaty), but the title also mentions leaving NATO. Can you clarify what are you asking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Various EU states are also NATO members. Others are not.

- There are various EU politicians who favor *their* country leaving NATO or dissolving NATO. Generally that is not a mainstream position, but [some](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Left_(Germany)) are strong enough to get seats in parliament.
- As mentioned in the comments, EU-member military forces (some of which are also NATO forces) are cooperating within the EU framework.

So the meaningful question would be along the lines of "are there relevant EU politicians who want to merge the various national armies into a single army?"

I would say that there are no *relevant* ones.